# Permutations of k elements in n positions

Tags: combinatorics

Considering the following expression (Uspensky 1937, p. 18):

$_{n} P_{k} \equiv \frac{n !}{(n-k) !}$

If $k=3$ and $n=6$, then the number of permutations ascend to 120.

$_{n} P_{k} \equiv \frac{6 !}{(6-3) !}=120$

If the restriction is that there can not be like-neighbours, is the above expression valid? (see computational implementation in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566191/permutations-of-3-elements-within-6-positions). In case not, how should be modified?

Thanks in advance, all interesting comments will be rewarded.

Comment: Do you mean cannot or can not? There is a difference! Also, what do you mean by like-neighbours? The problem you linked to does not involve permutations ($_nP_k$) but tuples where repetition is allowed ($n^k$).

Comment: Luke, thank you for commenting; I guess it is "cannot". Non-like-neighbours means that as the example shows, a sequence with "aabcab" cannot be considered because of the "aa" (repeated neighbour letter).

Comment: Since you are allowed to repeat the letters (you can have multiple $a$'s), then that is not a permutation, but a tuple (or string) drawn from $\{a,b,c\}$. Thus the number is $n^k$ not $_nP_k$. See my answer.

Comment: I see.  You're right. Let me ask you something; what happens if the number of elements surpasses the positions?

Comment: If by positions you mean $k$ (the length of the word), then in that case, you do not use all of the letters. The formula is still valid.

Comment: The title says $n$ positions. Let’s just say that if there is an alphabet with $a$ distinct letters and words using $p$ letters (from the $a$ with repeats ) then there are $a^p$ in all but a(a-1)^{p-1}$ with no two identical adjacent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the problem you linked, $k$ out of $n$ objects are being chosen with repetition allowed, and order important. This can be done in $n^k$ ways.

If you want that no two adjacent letters of the $k$ chosen are the same, then you have $n$ options for the first letter, and $n-1$ for each of the following letters (since each one is different from the neighbour on its left). Thus there are $n(n-1)^{k-1}$ ways.

Comment: No, it's $3\times (3-1)^{6-1} = 3\times 2^5 = 96$. (We are choosing $k=6$ out of the set $\{a,b,c\}$ of size $n=3$.)

Comment: It sounds like $k=3$ letters and $n=6$ positions

Comment: $k$ is how much we are choosing out of $n$.

Comment: But then, the expression I gave should be different too?

Comment: No, we are choosing $k=6$ letters to from a word out of $n=3$ possible letters.

Comment: I would like to understand better this. Is the point of departure $n^k$?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition). Note: do not be confused, unfortunately the wikipedia uses the letters $n$ and $k$ oppositely to how I used them here.

Comment: " but if restrictions are placed on how often an element can appear, this formula is no longer valid." Yes, no problem with the letter denomination.

Comment: We have no restrictions in your case, unless you have say, a maximum of 5 $a$'s (for example).

Comment: So how do we get $n(n-1)^k-1$ from $n^k$ wikipedia is not so explicit at this.

Comment: The reasoning is explained in my answer: first you pick the first letter (there are $n$ ways to do this). Then you pick the second letter (there are $n-1$ ways to do this, since it must be different from the first letter). Then you pick the third (also $n-1$ ways since it must be different from the second letter), and so on until $k$ are picked.

You end up with $n\underbrace{(n-1)\cdots(n-1)}_{\text{$k-1$ times}}=n(n-1)^{k-1}$ ways to choose $k$ letters.